# Subwoofer Amplifier Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit

I've had asked many sites but they don't leave any answers.

I want to build a subwoofer only without using a crossover and I want to know what should I include in the power amplifier circuit.

Can I include a tone control inside it or made it in a different circuit instead?
And what about the low pass filter circuit? I need explanation please

Comment: Smileys and weird emojis don't really agree with this site

Comment: Let me make it simple. I want to build a subwoofer that has output power below than 100W. So how do i design the circuit without using a crossover? And also i want to know how the flow of the circuit from the input to the output.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to build a subwoofer only without using a crossover,

You say that, then

> And what about the low pass filter cct?

For a sub pass band, you have a low pass anywhere from 80-120Hz, system dependent, and typically a high pass at 20-50Hz. Those filters are just a crossover with a different name. The low pass filter is critical, or your sub will overlap with the low pass band. This is bad. You do not want energy outside of the sub pass band going to your subs. You'll probably want a 4th order or higher Linkwitz-Riley or Butterworth low pass in front of the amplifier. The high pass doesn't usually have to be as steep, probably a second or third order Butterworth or Bessel.

> i want to know what should i include in the power amplifier cct..

Subs need a lot of power to do anything useful. You have not stated what kind of power levels you're looking at, so its a guessing game what you actually need. A class D amplifier is probably your best bet. A book could be written about that this point.

> Can i include a tone control inside it or made it in a different cct
>   instead...

Nothing says "I'm a cheap, junk, piece of consumer audio equipment" like a tone control knob. At the end of the day, it's usually a variable high pass filter, and is really just a toy. Leave it off.